# I need a regular expression for password in pl-sql using regexp_like

Tags: regex, plsql, oracle11g

Regexp must enforce these rules

1. First symbol must be only uppercase or lowercase letter
2. Password length must be at least 8 characters
3. Password must contain at least one digit, uppercase and lowercase letters
4. Password must not contain a space and special characters

Comment: what do you mean by uppercase symbol?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried; this isn't `weworkforfree.com`.

Comment: Why do you need a single regular expression?  Why not have a few expressions that are combined?  Define "symbol" in point 1-- are you saying that you only want an alphabetic character A-Z?  Define "special characters" in point 4-- are you saying that you want to restrict the password to, say, alphanumeric characters (A-Z and 0-9)?

Comment: Excuse me, i mean a letter. I' ll fix it

Comment: For example password must be like that: fooBar123

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle does not support lookarounds. For that reason, if you want to use `REGEXP_LIKE`, we'll need to split it into two regexps:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(mycolumn, '^.*[0-9]', 'c')
AND REGEXP_LIKE(mycolumn, '^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{7,}$', 'c');
```

**Explanation**

- `^.*[0-9]` ensures there is at least one digit
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `[a-zA-Z]` matches the initial letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,}` matches 7 or more chars (ensuring 8 or more total) that are either ASCII letters or digits
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string